# Error:Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbads:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, react-native

After I clone from `gitlab` a `react-native` project

```
npm install
```

[image: Image 1]

```
react-native run-android
```

[image: Image 2]

```
add --stacktrace
```

[image: Image 3]

But I do have build tool 23.0.1. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ADB configuration may be missing

MyComputer-Properties-Advances System Settings-System Properties-Environment Variable - User variable

here add path to tool inside android SDK

pathto SDK/platform-tools

Comment: I have fixed it by thist commond sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot when you ran with --stacktrace you can actually see the error:

> Cannot run program: "/home/ljh/work/software/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt"

and then the error in Chinese saying:

> "No file or directory"

Make sure the file `/home/ljh/work/software/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt` actually exists, or if it does, try to execute it by hand form that directory ("*$ aapt package -h*") to see if an anti-virus isn't blocking it.